# Grails Domain Create Association Table

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have a question about creating an associative table, in grails, to reconcile a many-to-many relationship.  The setup is this:
1.  Domain A (Client Profile) can have many Domain B (Friends)
2.  Each Domain B (Friends) can have many Domain A (Client Profile)
3.  To Resolve this, I need to create an Associative table (or domain) that has FK's from each table.  This domain can be named Domain C (client_friend)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class DomainA{
    String id
String firstName
String lastName
    static hasMany = [domainB: DomainB]
    static mapping = {
    cache true
    id generator: 'assigned'

    columns {
        firstName   type:'text'
        lastName    type:'text'
        alumConnections column: 'domaina_id', joinTable: 'a_b'
    }

}
static constraints = {
    firstName   (nullable:true)
    lastName    (nullable:true)
}

  }
```

DomainB Code:

```
   class DomainB{   
String id
String firstName
String lastName

    static hasMany = [domainA:DomainA]
static belongsTo = DomainA
static mapping = {
    cache true
    id generator: 'assigned'        

             columns {                  
        firstName       type:'text'
        lastName        type:'text'
        domainA column: 'domainb_id', joinTable: 'a_b'
    }
}
static constraints = {  
    firstName       (nullable:true)
    lastName        (nullable:true)

}
  }
```

Domain A_B code:

```
 class AB{


Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
long version

  }
```

When I run this code, it seems to work.  The tables, using MySQL, are created, FK seem to be in place.  When I enter data into the DomainB class, data is entered and both PK's from DomainA and DomainB are inserted into A_B.  But, the problems comes when I try to delete values from A_B.  I've tried something like this:

```
     AB results =AB.findByAIdAndBId('jIi-hRi4cI','2BYvuA2X14')
```

but get an error:  InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [a_id] for class [class mgr.AB]

My question is this: first, have i set this up correctly?  Second, if so, how then do i query the AB table who's PK is made up of a composite of DomainA and DomainB?

Thanks for any help.

jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your composite class isn't entirely correct. Look at this example and adjust yours accordingly.  This is how I do all my composite domains:

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {

    User user
    Role role

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.user?.id == user?.id &&
            other.role?.id == role?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (user) builder.append(user.id)
        if (role) builder.append(role.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
        find 'from UserRole where user.id=:userId and role.id=:roleId',
            [userId: userId, roleId: roleId]
    }

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        UserRole instance = UserRole.findByUserAndRole(user, role)
        instance ? instance.delete(flush: flush) : false
    }

    static void removeAll(User user) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
    }

    static void removeAll(Role role) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE role=:role', [role: role]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['role', 'user']
        version false
    }
}
```

Once you have that, there is no need for the belongsTo and hasMany associations.  But to access the data from those domains, you can provide methods like the following:

```
class User {

   // typical domain junk

   Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
     UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
   }
}
```

Then you can do things like userInstance.authorites just as if the hasMany was there.  Basically, you're doing what Grails would typical do for you.  But this is actually a good thing.  Collections in Grails can be costly if not done right.  This is being addressed in 2.0 with the use of Bags.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  What about, in my example, DomainA and DomainB?  Do i need to get rid of their 'belongs to' and 'has many's'?

Comment: Yes, there is no need for them.  I'll update my answer to reflect how to handle that.

Comment: I implemented these changes and it seems to be ok.  thanks again!